# How to update res files from blackberry app after compiled?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

im creating an app that must be generic, so i got a generic layout where a logo , a title and a body can be changed from xml or png files. At the moment i have to change the xmls and pngs and then compile to see the changes in the app.

so i wonder if is there a way to updates the deliverables files, where the jar is so i dont have to compile everytime i make a change on files?...

I have done this:

•I tryed modifying the jar by just opening as a zip and changuing the files myself.

•Using the comand to updates jars files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Im using blackberry eclipse pluging and my app is designed for devices  5.0 to 7.1

**EDIT**: When i try to modify the jar it changes but when i install it on device it has the same configuration from the last time that it was compiled.

**EDIT**: Also i would like to know if its posible to change package name since when 2 apps have the same package it just overwrite when i download it

Comment: I have never done this myself, but I have heard about people who have.  Once you have updated the jar, you should be able to rebuild the cod file and then sign the result - I believe that should work. You will need to review the rapc command to understand what to do with your updated jar - basically repeat what it does with the jar during a normal build, but use your updated jar.

Comment: @Peter Strange Well i guess i will have to search for rebuild .cod/sign by console since i am using eclipse pluging i don't know the whole background process, at least now i know it can be done thnx. if someone have done this i would apreciate your help :) .

Comment: "i will have to search for rebuild .cod/sign".  Watch the eclipse console output when you do the build - it will show you.....  You should be able to select the lines and copy them into a bat file.  you might need to be careful about what directory you are in when you execute them.  Good luck.

Comment: "if its possible to change package name " AFAIK, you can not change the package name once the jar has been built, just the assets (resources).  Package names can be shared by apps - for example for libraries, though there are a few gotchas. Search around for this and start a new question if you think you need to change a package name. I have never had the need to and can't think of a circumstance where I would do this.

Comment: @PeterStrange thank you for your responds. Well i will explain my circumstance, im putting my deliverables files on my server with my default app (my logo,my tittle, my body) . My app should be generic therefor if i want to make a new one ( the same app but different logo/tittle/body) i need to change the projectname so if i want to download it, it doesn't overwrite the oldone when it installs. i don't know if i explain myself hahaha.

Comment: If your app persists anything using PersistentStore, what you are trying to do will not be possible.